# Application get stuck when drawing nearly 40 Scatter Plots using Core Plot in IPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, ios5, core-plot

I am developing an iPad app , it has the option to show Scatter Plots user able to plot the points.I have used core plot library.i have to show 40 Scatter plots in a view controller. my application becomes not responding and get quits when i load 25 graphs.

1. Is there any limitation (No.of Scatter plot counts) in Core plot for a View Controller to show?
2. What is the optimal way to load Scatter Plots using Core Plot?

Answer (score 1):

There's no hard limit on the number of graphs, but you will eventually run out of memory and/or other GPU resources. The maximum number you can show in a particular app will depend on the physical size and complexity of the graphs as well as the hardware it's running on.

If all 40 plots need to be visible at the same time, try setting `collapsesLayers` to YES on the hosting view so each graph only uses one Core Animation layer. Another technique that you can use if you don't need the graphs to be interactive is to render each graph into an image using the `-imageOfLayer` method and display those on screen. You can release the graph after rendering.